# Count features Pandas based on two features to generate two new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to generate column counts based on two columns
I have column A, which is data from 0 to 1000 in 0.5 range increments. (0.5, 1, 1.5 ... 1000), and column B which is 'Yes', 'No'.)

I'm trying to generate new columns C (yes's) and D (no's)
which are counts of yes's and no's at 0.5, at 1, etc.

So something like

```
0.5    Y   
5      N
0.5    N
5      N
2      Y
3      N
```

would Generate

```
0.5    Y    1   1
5      N    0   2
0.5    N    1   1
5      N    0   2
2      Y    1   0
3      N    0   1
```

I using groupby:

groupby('columnA')['ColumnB'].transform('count')

but it wasn't giving me what I was looking for. Splitting them up by 'Y and N' before hand also doesn't do exactly what I want.

Thanks

Comment: For sure! The third column is the count of how many Y's (second column) occur for the value in the first column over all values. The fourth column, is the count of how many 'N's) occur for that count over all columns. I could manually split by each value in column 1 and 2, count each individually, and then merge them back together, but I figured there's a really simple way I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1**:

```
df=df.join( df.groupby('columnA')['columnB']
              .value_counts()
              .unstack(fill_value=0) ,on='columnA' )

print(df)
```

**Method 2**

```
df=df.join( df.groupby(['columnA','columnB'])
              .size()
              .unstack(fill_value=0), on='columnA' )
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   columnA columnB  N  Y
0      0.5       Y  1  1
1      5.0       N  2  0
2      0.5       N  1  1
3      5.0       N  2  0
4      2.0       Y  0  1
5      3.0       N  1  0
```

Comment: Damn, that works, but made hundreds of millions of rows. Removing them using df.loc[~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')] works. Is there a way without generating all the extra cases?

Comment: I forgot that here it is necessary to concat instead of joining by duplicate rows, check now :)

Comment: Thanks, this is now producing some extra columns for some reason and giving them Nan values. Whereas before, if I removed the duplicates it was correct.@abhilb's generates them correctly.

Comment: @ansev i saw your post only after posting my solution. i will delete mine. no need of aspersions

Comment: Edit, Method 2 solution is good! Thanks @ansev. I'm not sure why method 2 works, but method 1 generates extra Nan columns. Not that it matters for my purposes. Thanks again.

Comment: I removed the `pd.concat` method.I recommend you to use Method 1. It could be faster in large dataframes. I am glad to help:)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
data.groupby(['columnA', 'columnB']).count()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried that in the past, it doesn't give the format I want. I'm trying to figure out how to make it go/map directly into my two new columns.

Comment: Would joining the output of this to your existing table on columns A and B work for you?